# How to make use of $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX in spec file?

Tags: rpm, prefix, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

We are trying to make a relocatable rpm and wanted to use the prefixs below to relocate the files .

```
Prefix: %{buildroot}/etc 
Prefix: %{buildroot}/usr/bin 
Prefix: %{buildroot}/usr/sbin 
Prefix: %{buildroot}/usr/share 
Prefix: %{buildroot}/var 

    %install

    mkdir -p $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX
```

However we are not able to get the value of $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX while running the rpm build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX` is only available at install time (*e.g.* `%pre`) for relocatable RPMs (which nearly never work BTW). See http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-reloc-building-relocatable.html for more info.